# General question on the address generation using WavesCS

Tags: wavesplatform

I'm new to WAVES and I'm learning by experimenting. I just want to know if unlike masternode coins where addresses are stored in the wallet file, with WavesCS, once you generate a seed and create a private key out of it, is the wallet address generated can be used already as is without the need to write to the wallet file or to the blockchain itself?

```
Node node = new Node();
String walletSeed = PrivateKeyAccount.GenerateSeed();
PrivateKeyAccount privateKeyAccount = PrivateKeyAccount.CreateFromSeed(walletSeed, node.ChainId, 0);
String walletAddress.Text = privateKeyAccount.Address;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experiment, the answer is yes to my question. All addresses generated from seed by PrivateKetAccount will already work as is and can be imported to other WAVES wallet using the seed. On the other hand, if you use /Addresses post method with corresponding API Key, you generate address but it can't be imported since the address is tied to the seed of the main node wallet.